# Varchar values transform into 0 in php mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8, arabic

I have a MySQL database containing tables with Arabic data (Varchar type exactly), I try to print a select query string thought php but it prints the values as zeros, Here's my query :

```
SELECT *,(
CASE WHEN `name_singular`= "قَائِدان" THEN "name_singular"
WHEN `name_twoA`= "قَائِدان" THEN "name_twoA"
WHEN `name_pluralA`= "قَائِدان" THEN "name_pluralA"
WHEN `name_twoO`= "قَائِدان" THEN "name_twoO"
WHEN `name_pluralO`= "قَائِدان" THEN
"name_pluralO" else NULL END) AS `field`
FROM `name` WHERE `name_singular`= "قَائِدان" OR
`name_twoA`= "قَائِدان" OR
`name_pluralA`= "قَائِدان" OR
`name_twoO`= "قَائِدان" OR
`name_pluralO`= "قَائِدان" LIMIT 0, 10 ;
```

and that's what i got as a result of printing the query string.
it works fine when executing it thought mysql directly, but when using php it returns `null`

```
SELECT *, 
( CASE 
WHEN `name_singular` = "0" THEN "name_singular" 
WHEN `name_twoa` = "0" THEN "name_twoa" 
WHEN `name_plurala` = "0" THEN "name_plurala" 
WHEN `name_twoo` = "0" THEN "name_twoo" 
WHEN `name_pluralo` = "0" THEN "name_pluralo" 
ELSE NULL 
end ) AS `field` 
FROM   `name` 
WHERE  `name_singular` = "0" 
OR `name_twoa` = "0" 
OR `name_plurala` = "0" 
OR `name_twoo` = "0" 
OR `name_pluralo` = "0" 
LIMIT  0, 10
```

And that's the php code :

```
<?php $query = 'the query string above '; 
echo $query; $array=mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query($query));
var_dump($array); 
?>
```

Comment: Check the following: Is the database connection set to utf8(mb4)? Is the file encoding set to UTF-8 without BOM? Do you tell the browser the charset is UTF-8? Do you use the MultiByte extension where appropriate?

Comment: 1) database connection set to utf8(mb4) : check 
2) file encoding set to UTF-8 without BOM : check 
3) browser encoding set to UTF-8 : check 
the last one i didn't understand it 
and the problem still existing

Comment: Show the PHP code that's having the problem.

Comment: @Barmar you could consider the php code like this : 
`<?php
$query = 'the query string above ';
echo $query; 
$array= mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query($query));
var_dump($array); 
?>`
because i have this at many functions separated in many files, but i'm sure they're working..

Comment: @StarsQueen Put it in the question, it's hard to read code in comments.

Comment: What is the second query in the question for?

Comment: @Barmar i have added the php code above , the second query isn't code it's the result of printing the query 
sorry i'm new here !

Comment: Can you give us the code that creates the query string? And maybe an example of a data row?

Comment: Are you displaying that on a web page?  If so, what does the `<meta>` tag look like?

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_*` interface; change to the `mysqli_*` interface.